# How to show tooltips in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts

Following the tutorial this code draws the line chart, but no tooltips. Am I missing some configuration option here? In the tutorial there are tooltips showing up.

```
var chartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData, {
    showTooltip: true,
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>"
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What version of chart.js are you using?

I can confirm that [tooltips work using v1.0.1-beta2](http://jsfiddle.net/cL29e5vr/)

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

but do not work [using v0.2.0](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmm8h6jq/).

Version 1.0.1-beta2 is available from cdnjs.

Comment: Confirmed, v0.2.0 is the version currently available on NuGet (26/09/14), typical...

Comment: Yeah I grabbed it with bower. My code worked after loaded Chart.js from CDN

Comment: I got it via Nuget and had the same problem. I had to get the latest version from https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js.

Comment: it was because i used the version from bower package and it had a much lower version stable by that time

Answer (score 1):

It works and shows tooltips properly.. Do you get any error in the console?

Here's how I used your code:

```
var chartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};

window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    window.myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData, {
        showTooltip: true,
        tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put backgroundColor with a single value instead a array:

```
datasets: [{
    label: "# of beauty womens",
    data: [12, 5, 3],
    backgroundColor: "#FC940B",
    fill: false,
    borderColor: "#FC940B"
}]
```

Hugs...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.