# Chart.js - y axis custom label

Tags: javascript, label, chart.js

I have simple line graph which is show some progress. There are dates on x-axis a and status (1 to 5) on y-axis. Data will always be from 1 to 5. But what I need is to change labels on y-axis (and labels on point hover too) from numbers to showing progress by text string. For example where is 1 a I need text string with "request added", on 2 "request viewed", on 3 "request accepted" on 4 "request solved" and on 5 "solving confirmed". I think there is no native way to achieve this, but maybe someone will know how to edit Chart.js to make it.

Here is a picture how it looks now, with these number: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w30il1k9t5wll53/Screenshot%202015-04-17%2014.55.00.png?dl=0)

Sorry for my english and thx for any help!

Comment: Why can't you use the `label` attribute?

Comment: @Jean-Paul beacuse label att is on x-axis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the scaleLabel function. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28700578/909535

```
scaleLabel: function (valuePayload) {
if(Number(valuePayload.value)===1)    
return 'request added';
if(Number(valuePayload.value)===2)    
return 'request viewed';
if(Number(valuePayload.value)===3)    
return 'request accepted';
if(Number(valuePayload.value)===4)    
return 'request solved';
if(Number(valuePayload.value)===5)    
return 'solving confirmed';
}
```

Comment: It returns undefined: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzr24ds6r8e03in/Screenshot%202015-04-17%2015.16.43.png?dl=0

Comment: Updated the answer..Try now.. Could you provide your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Now it is work great, thx. And how to achieve same thing in pop-up when I hover a point in graph?

Comment: Ok can you provide a jsfiddle so that everyone can see what your code is? Also accept the answer if it solves the issue!

Comment: JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/6xV78/ I will accept answer as soon as second part of question will be solved. Thx again for help :)

Comment: Are you sure you have the right fiddle your screenshot looks different from this one!!

Comment: JSfiddle is for exemple, I can't use whole my code, because it is generated by php from mysql tables and so on...

Comment: It's similar to this one except you have to use  `showTooltip: true,`
        `tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>" `and more info can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25208214/909535