# How to get tooltip on chart.js v1.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart, chart.js

I have tried 
[Chart JS custom tooltip option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338141/chart-js-custom-tooltip-option)
and 
[How to show tooltips in Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525931/how-to-show-tooltips-in-chart-js)

One among many attempts of mine are:

```
    new Chart(document.getElementById("location").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData2,{
    showTooltip: true,
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",
     //Option for title font size in pixels
     tooltipTitleFontSize: 14, 

     //Option for tooltip title color
     tooltipTitleFontColor: "#eee",
     });
```

but both of no use to me I have tried every possibility and I'm not able to know what is stopping the tooltip from working.
Nothing there in the console to debug so any suggestion would be thankful

Comment: I'm a newbie so it will take me a few days to learn making fiddle of my program @ℊααnd

Comment: The best thing for me was to change to the new version it will take me some days to fix the projects but I think that'll be helpful later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Chart(document.getElementById("location").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData2**)**,{
showTooltip: true,
tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",
 //Option for title font size in pixels
 tooltipTitleFontSize: 14, 

 //Option for tooltip title color
 tooltipTitleFontColor: "#eee",
 });
```

See the above code....are you missing a parenthesis after barChartData2?

Comment: OMG how can I forget that ? O yeah I think I'm passing the second object as a json to the function so no need to close it beforehand